# Помогите создать рабочий EXE файл приложения C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, inno-setup, .net-4.8

Помогите разобраться как собрать рабочий EXE файл который бы работал на другом ПК(не на том где создавался). В Visual Studio выбираю Release, отладка, начать отладку, потом  с помощью Inno Setup Compiler (смотрел 3 инструкции) создаю установщик из EXE файла который находиться bin\Release и так же добавляю саму папку Release, когда последующие разы пробовал собрать добавлял еще дополнительно папку \packages, так как там есть файлы MaterialDesign, думал может поможет, но когда устанавливаю на другом ПК саму программу потом запустить не могу, а на основном пк после установки все хорошо запускается, подскажите, может в сборку еще нужно, что-то добавлять?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Абстрагируйтесь от установщика, пакетов и прочего, начните с простого, а именно, что на чем написан проект, ибо это очень важно. Это .NET или .NET Framework? Если первое, то установлен-ли `Runtime` на том компьютере, на котором запускаете? Может собрали со встроенным фреймворком? Далее, как ведет себя проект на другом компьютере, какие ошибки дает (если нет логирования, то изучайте журнал Windows), ну и так далее. Как видите, весьма индивидуальный случай, ответ на который можете знать только вы...

Comment: написан на WPF (.NET Framework), так же использовал для дизайна MaterialDesign, добавил скрин с другого ПК из журнала

Comment: Вам не кажется странным скрин, на котором написано "Ошибка"? Для вас вот слово "Ошибка" дает что либо? Думаю нет. Так может приведете саму ошибку, ее стактрейс?

Comment: добавил еще пару скринов

Comment: я видно был сильно наивен когда купился на то, что на C# можно написать приложение и оно запуститься на любом ПК

Comment: Вместо того, чтоб замазывать всякую приватную информацию, достаточно вместо скрина приложить **текстом** ошибку... Ну а что касается ошибки - вам пишет "файл отсутствует", и вроде что-то в XAML у вас такое, чего имеет либо явно захардкоженный путь (например `<Image Source = "C:\Folder\Image.png"/>` - строго прописывается конкретный диск, папка, название файла), либо у вас там используется к примеру контрол, библиотеки которого вы не переносите. Ну а по имеющимся данным, решить проблему можете только вы... Ну либо кидайте проект целиком.

Comment: Да, есть иконки с полным путем, так как по-другому их не получалось добавить, а ошибка про .NET Runtime что значит? То есть он не установлен и без этого него проекты написанные на WPF (.NET Framework) бесполезны и не будут работать на других пк?

Comment: `Да, есть иконки с полным путем` - ну вот это скорей всего и ваша проблема, пишите относительный путь. `ошибка про .NET Runtime` - Runtime, это любой .NET проект, это не значит что его нет, это значит что это ваш проект написан на .NET технологиях. `То есть он не установлен` - .NET Framework установлен по умолчанию на всех современных OS, если его не было бы, то и ошибку вы не получили. `не будут работать на других пк` - если нет рантайма, да, проект даже не запустится, а вы как хотели, когда ссылаетесь в проекте на чужой код? Допустим `File.ReadAllText("...")` - по вашему, где этот `File`?

Comment: Осталось понять как сделать относительные пути которые не выдавали бы ошибки когда выполняется отладка

Comment: Без указания полного пути до директории. Условно путь до проекта `C:/SomeFolder/Super.exe`, то есть при запуске рабочей директорией будет `C:/SomeFolder`, ну а относительный путь до картинки будет тогда к примеру `/Images/Icon.png`, что будет эквиваленту `C:/SomeFolder/Images/Icon.png`. Ну условно что-то [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqVZQ.png)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Переходите на .NET 5+, там можно нативно собрать весь проект в один файл. Картинки можно собирать как ресурсы, тогда они встроятся в сам исполняемый файл. Так можно делать, если картинки никогда не меняются и их не много.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обойтись без деплоев. Это некое "inno-setup" - это деплой, и это обычно сложно настраиваемые системы. Всё ваше напрограммированное(+ресурсы) поместите (запакуйте) в тот же зип-архив (рар-архив), и перенесите на сторонние компьютеры. Вы это всё перенесёте именно так, что будете уверены в том, что деплой на ваше напрограммированное(+ресурсы) - не влияет. Ещё имейте ввиду то, что анти-малварь относится к деплоям крайне "чувствительно", т.е. всё то что лежит в одном екзешнике и "распаковывается" из него в кучу всякого разного - потенциально рассматривается как набор "вирусни". Далее - всегда и повсеместно существует проблема с путями. Ваше ПО(+ресурсы) работает на определённых путях, но подавляюще часто при переносе куда либо - возникают проблемы с путями. Т.е. ваше ПО на стороннем компьютере может не видеть некоторые части себя. И кстати, все эти деплой-системы обычно и имеют массу проблем с путями.
И как @EvgeniyZ написал - проверьте рантаймы.

П.С.: Позанудствую. Любая система должна быть инвариантной относительно любого окружения. Т.е. вообще то строго говоря - проверьте всё то что вы делаете НА ТОМ ЖЕ КОМПЬЮТЕРЕ. Соберите всё то что вы наделали в один пакет, и ставьте его в разные места. Хоть пятьдесят экземпляров ставьте - должно работать. Это первый этап проверки. Это когда оно должно работать "там же", но с немножко другими условиями.

П.П.С.: Похоже что внедрённый ресурс "отрабатывает" не так как положено. Такое бывает когда он (ресурс) вызывается на некоей обычной конфигурации, а на другой - уже нет. Просмотрите все те места, где у вас как либо идёт вызов ресурсов, и постарайтесь всё это вынести во внешние ресурсы, т.е. в файлы. Существует проблема внутреннего хранения ресурсов в сборках, и обращение к этим ресурсам далеко не тривиальное. Сразу и сходу вы в этом не разберётесь. А значит сделайте проще - все ресурсы сделайте внешними (т.е. все ресурсы - это файлы), т.е. не внедряйте ресурсы в сборки.